# Getting frame of programmatically created subviews

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a programmatically created subviews, `view1`. I am adding some `UIButtons` to it, but the measurements of these buttons depend on `view1.frame.height`. However, I can only seem to get the value in `viewDidAppear`, which obviously is not what I want. Moreover, if I put my `addButtons()` function in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, I get an infinite loop. The results of putting `addButtons()` in various UIViewController functions is as follows (in comments):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addView1()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    print(view1.frame.height)  // 0.0 first time it is called, 74.0, which is right, the second time it is called, but I got into an infinite loop
    //addButtons() -> infinite loop
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print(view1.frame.height) //0.0
}

override func  viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    print(view1.frame.height) //74.0, the value I want, but obviously not where I want it
}
```

My `addButtons()` looks like this:

```
 func addButtons(){

    let mon = UIButton()
    let tue = UIButton()
    let wed = UIButton()
    let thu = UIButton()
    let fri = UIButton()
    let sat = UIButton()
    let sun = UIButton()


    let buttonsArray = ["mon": mon, "tue": tue, "wed": wed, "thu": thu, "fri": fri, "sat": sat, "sun": sun]
    let daysArray1 = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"]
    var daysArray2 = ["mon": "M", "tue":"T", "wed": "W", "thu": "T", "fri": "F", "sat": "S", "sun": "S"]
    let buttonSide = view1.frame.height * 0.6

    let distance = (view1.frame.width - buttonSide * 7) / 8.0
    var count = 0

    for day in daysArray1{
        let offSet = (buttonSide ) * CGFloat(count) + distance * CGFloat(count + 1)
        let centerX = (buttonSide / 2) + offSet



        buttonsArray[day]!.setTitle(daysArray2[day], forState: .Normal)

        buttonsArray[day]!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        buttonsArray[day]!.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        view1.addSubview(buttonsArray[day]!)

        view1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonsArray[day]!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        view1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonsArray[day]!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view1, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: centerX))
        view1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonsArray[day]!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: buttonSide))
        view1.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonsArray[day]!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: buttonSide))
        count += 1


    }
```

Comment: "but obviously not where I want it" .... where else do you want it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you add a button to your view the system calls viewDidLayoutSubviews which you keep adding buttons and the system keeps calling viewDidLayoutSubviews. You should add your buttons when viewDidLoad().
To match the height of the view you can:

> - Pin all buttons to Trailing and Leading edge of the view
> - Pin the first button's Top with view's Top Edge
> - Pin the last button's Bottom with view's Bottom
> - Pin each button's Top with the previous button's Bottom edge (given is not the first button)
> - Constraint all buttons .Height to match view's .Height with a multiplier of 0.6

This is an example I did using [PureLayout](https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout)

```
    let someView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    view.addSubview(someView)
    var prev: UIButton?
    for i in 0..<6 {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
        button.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.randomColor(), forUIControlState: .Normal)
        someView.addSubview(button)
        button.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing)
        button.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading)
        button.autoMatchDimension(.Height, toDimension: .Height, ofView: someView, withMultiplier: 0.6)
        if let previous = prev {
            button.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: previous)
        } else {
            button.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
        }
        prev = button
    }

    someView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Trailing)
    someView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Leading)
    someView.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
    someView.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 100)
```

**UPDATE(equal horizontal spacing)**

OK based your comment, I got that you also need equal spacing between buttons as well as the side edges of the parent container. where is a full working view controller class:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let wrapper = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
        view.addSubview(wrapper)
        wrapper.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        var previous: (button: UIButton, spacer: UIView)?
        for day in ["M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"] {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
            let spacer = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
            button.setTitle(day, forState: .Normal)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            wrapper.addSubview(button)
            wrapper.addSubview(spacer)

            //set height 60% of wrapper
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: button,
                attribute: .Height,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: wrapper,
                attribute: .Height,
                multiplier: 0.6,
                constant: 0))

            //set width same has height
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: button,
                attribute: .Height,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: button,
                attribute: .Width,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))

            //pin button leading with spacer trailing
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: button,
                attribute: .Leading,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: spacer,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))


            //pin spacer trailing with button leading
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: spacer,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: button,
                attribute: .Leading,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))

            //align button to center
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: button,
                attribute: .CenterY,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: wrapper,
                attribute: .CenterY,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))

            if let previous = previous {
                //pin spacer Leading with previous button trailing
                wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                    item: spacer,
                    attribute: .Leading,
                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                    toItem: previous.button,
                    attribute: .Trailing,
                    multiplier: 1,
                    constant: 0))

                //pin previous button's Trailing with spacer Leading
                wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                    item: previous.button,
                    attribute: .Trailing,
                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                    toItem: spacer,
                    attribute: .Leading,
                    multiplier: 1,
                    constant: 0))

                //set spacer's width same as previous spacer
                wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                    item: spacer,
                    attribute: .Width,
                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                    toItem: previous.spacer,
                    attribute: .Width,
                    multiplier: 1,
                    constant: 0))

            } else {
                //this is the first item, pin the spacer Leading to wrapper Leading
                wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                    item: spacer,
                    attribute: .Leading,
                    relatedBy: .Equal,
                    toItem: wrapper,
                    attribute: .Leading,
                    multiplier: 1,
                    constant: 0))
            }

            previous = (button: button, spacer: spacer)
        }
        // last spacer
        if let previous = previous {
            let spacer = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
            spacer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            wrapper.addSubview(spacer)
            //pin spacer Leading with previous button trailing
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: spacer,
                attribute: .Leading,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: previous.button,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))


            //pin previous button's Trailing with spacer Leading
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: previous.button,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: spacer,
                attribute: .Leading,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))

            //set spacer's width same as previous spacer
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: spacer,
                attribute: .Width,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: previous.spacer,
                attribute: .Width,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))

            //pin spacer's Trailing with wrappper Trailing
            wrapper.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: spacer,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: wrapper,
                attribute: .Trailing,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0))
        }

        wrapper.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 320, height: 40)
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm trying to set the height of the buttons to 60% of the height of their super view, which is why I need to get the frame of their super view first. Is there way to do that in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: Ahh - OK, Instead of matching .Height to previous you can match .Height of your view with a multiplier of 0.6 - I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I actually have one more question: in my original code, I used this to calculate the distance between each button: `let distance = (view1.frame.width - buttonSide * 7) / 8.0`. Is there way to do it without invoking `view1.frame`?

Comment: @user245954 I'm having a hard time visualizing the layout you are trying to achieve could you quickly post an image of the layout you want?

Comment: Yea sure, this is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157544/equal-spacing-between-uibuttons-using-visual-format-language/33158176#33158176) I posted, the first answer solved the equal (horizontal) spacing between the buttons themselves, but what I wanted was equal  spacing between buttons and the container view (leading and trailing edges).

Comment: @user245954 K I updated my answer, take a look. I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Adrian: I was doing it with constants, after talking to some of my "developer" friends (their rationale was people would hardly notice it). But that seemed highly unprofessional to me, since I will have to use two sets of constants for the 6 and 6 plus screen sizes; more fundamentally it was the not how I understood how constraints should work.

Your answer actually helped me tremendously in finally getting an almost-full grasp of auto layout. Anyways, I'm very grateful for your detailed answer, and just want you to know that YOU DA REAL MVP.